# Error when trying to input Ant prefix attribute in gradle script

Tags: gradle, ant

**Problem**
No such property: prefix for class: org.gradle.api.task.bundling.War_Decorated. I am trying to convert my ant script to Gradle but I am stuck at the zipfileset with the prefix attribute.

**Ant Script**

```
 <war destfile="${dist.dir}/${warname}.war" update="true" >
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="place" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${label}" />
            <attribute name="Interface-Version" value="${Interface-Version}" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="Telescope WS" />
            <attribute name="Compiled-By" value="${user.name}" />
            <attribute name="Compiled-On" value="${TODAY}" />
            <attribute name="Sealed" value="false" />
        </manifest>

        <zipfileset dir="src/com/place/telescope" prefix="WEB-INF/classes/com/place/telescope">
            <include name="*.xml" />
        </zipfileset>
```

**Gradle Script**

```
 war {

    manifest {
        attributes ('Implementation-Vendor': 'Place',
        'Implementation-Version': "$label",
        'Interface-Version': project.'Interface-Version',
        'Implementation-Title': 'Telescope WS',
        'Compiled-By': 'user.name',
        'Compiled-On': 'TODAY',
        'Sealed': 'false')

    }
    archiveName 'MANIFEST.MF'
    //dependsOn 'zipAllfileset'
 }

war.manifest.writeTo('dist/warname.war/')

fileset(dir: 'src/com/place/telescope', includes: '*.xml',
        prefix = 'dist/warname.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/place/telescope')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error, Gradle/Groovy uses `attribute : value` instead of Ant `attribute = value`:

```
fileset(dir: 'src/com/place/telescope', includes: '*.xml',
        prefix: 'dist/warname.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/place/telescope')
```